# Crash when attempting to show an audience network rewarded video

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-audience-network

In our game we are using the Facebook SDK for Unity (v7.5.0), together with rewarded video mediation from IronSource.

The underlying Facebook SDK for Android is v4.11.0.

When attempting to show a rewarded video, our game crashes with this exception:

```
E/JavaBinder( 1172): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 521496)
W/ActivityManager( 1172): Exception when starting activity com.moonactive.coinmaster/com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity
W/ActivityManager( 1172): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 521496 bytes
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:1088)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2540)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2661)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:3493)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2613)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeTopActivitiesLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:5060)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.completePauseLocked(ActivityStack.java:1687)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.completePauseLocked(ActivityStack.java:1552)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityPausedLocked(ActivityStack.java:1474)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityPaused(ActivityManagerService.java:10204)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:547)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:4014)
W/ActivityManager( 1172):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
D/ActivityManager( 1172): isAutoRunBlockedApp:: com.moonactive.coinmaster, Auto Run ON
W/ActivityManager( 1172): Force removing ActivityRecord{6a0b73e u0 com.moonactive.coinmaster/com.moon.coinmaster.android.GameActivity t756}: app died, no saved state
```

Is this a known bug that has been resolved? I could not find any bugs similar to this.

Comment: FWIW, I started getting the same thing last Friday (FAN w/IronSource mediation).

Comment: When I "removed" IronSource's Facebook adapter, my crashes started to go away.  Still researching this, and I'm not claiming it's the FB adapter.  Just sharing.

Comment: How can you play videos without the adapter ?

Comment: You can't.  I did that as a test to isolate which adapter/code base was having an issue.  We removed (temporarily) FAN from our IronSource medication for Video and Interstials, and our crashes went away.  We also see the same crash in production code, which was released to the app store a few weeks ago, and we did not have this issue back then.  It's almost like it's Ad content related in combination with code.

Comment: What version of FB SDK are you using? the adapter doesn't include the SDK, and according to ironSource they support one of the latest version of the SDK. we are planning to upgrade the FB SDK and test again

Comment: I'm on Adapter version 3.0.3 (which for us, houses FB's SDK 4.19).  I'm in the process of upgrading, but those versions are on devices in our app store.  I was informed that the current adapter has the lasted FB SDK and does not have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Android SDK target 26+ has changed the way activities can pass data around -- basically they limited the amount of data that can be passed.

Eventually Facebook will release an updated *AudienceNetwork.aar* file to resolve this issue.

However, the workaround is as follows:

Unity automatically builds your Android project targeting the latest and greatest SDK available.  Most likely this is SDK 26 at this point.  There is no option in the Unity Editor to override this setting, but there IS an option to override the Minimum SDK Version.

1. Open your Unity project
2. Go to **File -> Build Settings**.  Make sure 'Android' is selected.
3. Click **Player Settings**, then on the right, click to expand **Other Settings**.
4. Take note of the "**Minimum API Level**".  There will be some text and a number, like **Android 4.1 'Jelly Bean' (API level 16)**.  The number you want, in my example, is the **16**.
5. Save and close your project.
6. Navigate to the root of your Unity project, then navigate to the **Assets/Plugins/Android** folder.
7. Edit the **AndroidManifest.xml** file there.

   The first line should start out: `<?xml ...`

   The second line should be something like `<manifest xmlns:android...`

   Insert THIS line as the 3rd line:

   `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />`

   Replace the "**16**" with whatever minimum Sdk version you want, from Step 4 above.  Set the **targetSdkVersion** to **25**, or 24, or whatever number you want -- it must be lower than 26.
8. Delete the **Temp** folder from your Unity project root.
9. Open Unity and rebuild your project.

If you're **not** on Unity, then just update your **targetSdkVersion** to 25 or lower -- updating the **AndroidManifest.xml** in your main project folder.  As of this morning, Facebook's latest still shows 4.25.0 and still does not work if you target Android SDK 26.